# Append to firebase array using the REST api

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase data:-

[image]

How can I append a new item to the actors array.

If I `post` a new item to `/actors.json` like:-

{
   "age": "42",
   "film": "Spiderman",
   "name": "Tobey Maguire"
}

Then it creates a random push-id and my `actors` array no more remains a array and I cannot use a `patch` method because I do not know the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the highest used (integer) index, 11 in your screenshot, you can do something like.

```
firebase.database.object('/actors/' + (index+1)).set({
age:42,
film:"Spiderman",
name:"Tobey Maguire
})
```

If you don't know it you can query the list first ofcourse

I don't see any advantage in using keys like this though..